# MySQL Error #1064 - creating user with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have MySQL 8.0.17 running on macOS 10.14.6 (Mojave). I am trying to create a new user with phpMyAdmin 4.8.2 (PHP version 7.1.23), but I keep getting error #1064 when I try to create it. I'm a little confused because the code is generated entirely be phpMyAdmin, so there should be no syntax errors.

Specifically, the error message is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_' at line 1
```

And here's the problematic (auto-generated) code:

```
CREATE USER 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password AS '***';GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON *.* TO 'user1'@'localhost' REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```

Can anyone help with this? Thanks!

Comment: Potentially a bug with phpMyAdmin. Try updating its version? 4.8.2 is a rather old version.